# Chrome Extension 'middle click or click' a link open new tab and don't close the popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I tried to click some link in my extension popup but after I click them, for example, "middle click -> open link in a new tab" with target _blank close my popup, how I can make it stay open. So in this way, i can click multiple links from my extension. Can i solve this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Java != Javascript.

Comment: I removed th java tag in your question. If you intended a javascript question, please add the appropriate javascript tag. But from your description, I cannot see, what language you are targeting...

Comment: In short, add a `click` listener that checks if the target is a link, uses chrome.tabs.create as shown in the linked answer, then `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Yes! Thanks solved with the @wOxxOm solution

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @xOxxOm

Solved with this!

```
   $('html').on('click', 'a', function(){
 event.preventDefault();
 chrome.tabs.create({url: $(this).attr('href'),active: false});
 });
```